# System-level crash in Windows Phone 8.1 app

Tags: windows, crash, windows-phone, windows-dev-center

[image: System-level crash]

It is a new feature in the Windows Dev Center to filter crashes by whether they are "System-level crash". If I select "True", there are a lot more crashes. Can you tell me what is a "System-level crash"?